# How to re-create DDN file or georeference output HDS

Tags: flopy

I have used the binary utility to read the .HDS  out put files from two models to calculate the difference (the drawdown), and I was wondering if there is a way to re-convert that into a .DDN binary file to reimport it into modflow.

Alternatively, is there a way to reference the row/column numbers in the array created from reading the HDS file so I can contour it and plot in a different program (i.e. Surfer)?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Astro, a possibility is to import the .hds file as a numpy array and export the numpy array as an ASCI grid by adding coordinates and cellsize.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, do you have any suggestions on how to add the coordinates and cell size?

Comment: Cell size depends on the units you are using. When using Modflow 2005 as executable coordinates can be added in the discretization package by adding an xul (x upper left) and yul (y upper left) documentation can be found here: https://modflowpy.github.io/flopydoc/mfdis.html

Comment: I am working with visual modflow (Vmod)... I am not sure how to use the dis file since the .nam file does not exist in Vmod...

Comment: I have no experience with VMod unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks for everything Dylan!

Comment: I found out how to do it .. I was trying to load the NAM files, but it doesn't seem to be necessary - I just did the following:

Comment: m = fp.modflow.Modflow()
dis = fp.modflow.ModflowDis.load('file.dis', m)

Comment: but I am not sure how to reference the HDS [layer, row, column] array to the .dis cell coordinates...